# Upload and retrieve images from azure blobs using .net core Web API and jquery

Tags: jquery, azure-blob-storage, .net-core-2.1, webapi

I am attempting to create a blog where you can post with images. Basically what I would like to do is select image from local machine then on button click to send it to azure blobs using a post method then retrieve and display the image on the web page using a get method.
I found this Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet
But I don't know how to apply it to a get and post method.
Also I tried this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
string connStr = "your_connection_string_here";

CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connStr);

CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = client.
GetContainerReference("myblobcontainer");

container.CreateIfNotExists();

CloudBlockBlob blob = container.
GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");


blob.UploadFromFile(@"C:\Test\Image1.jpg");

}
```

However I do not know how to apply this to a web api.
I have many doubts such as:
1. What should the get and post methods be?
2. how do I handle the image on client side in the get request and post request with jquery?
3. In what way do I send image through put and get request (JSON maybe)?
4. How do I get the image to a img tag?
5. How to identify which image belongs to what post

Would really appreciate the help. Sorry in advance if what I ask is not relevant or silly. I am still a student.
Note: I am using .net core 2.1

Comment: There is [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-javascript-client-libraries-v10#implement-the-html-page) you can follow to use Javascript to call Azure API's. I suggest you follow these and come back with more specific questions if you have any problems :-)

Comment: @SimplyGed Thanks for replying. I went through the documentation you linked, however i need to handle the uploading and retrieval from server side.

Comment: Maybe this like could help you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api

Comment: Hi @DuskHare, how's going? has your issue been solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked an Html page as client-side as a .net core api as backend. Try the code below :

**1.Client-side HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title> 
        Async file upload with jQuery 
    </title> 

    <script src= 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <div align="center"> 
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                id="myform"> 

            <div > 
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file" /> 
                <input type="button" class="button" value="Upload"
                        id="but_upload"> 
            </div> 
        </form> 

        </br>

        <div>
            <input type="button" id="but_display" value ="show all uploaded images">

            <div id="stage"></dev>

        </dev>
    </div>   

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("#but_upload").click(function() { 
                var fd = new FormData(); 
                var files = $('#file')[0].files[0]; 
                fd.append('file', files); 

                $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'https://localhost:44348/api/blob/', 
                    type: 'post', 
                    data: fd, 
                    contentType: false, 
                    processData: false, 
                    success: function(response){ 
                        if(response != 0){ 
                        alert('file uploaded'); 
                        } 
                        else{ 
                            alert('file not uploaded'); 
                        } 
                    }, 
                }); 
            });

            $("#but_display").click(function() { 
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'https://localhost:44348/api/blob/', 
                    type: 'get', 
                    success: function(response){ 
                        $("#stage").empty();
                        response.forEach((url)=>{

                            $("#stage").append("<img src='" + url +"' width='200' >");

                        })
                    }
                });

            });
        }); 
    </script> 
</body> 

</html>
```

**2.backend .net core API :**

1). Create a new .net core API project .
2). Go to `Startup.cs` , `ConfigureServices` method , paste the code below to replace it :

```
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.AddSingleton<CloudBlobClient>(sp => { return CloudStorageAccount.Parse("<your storage account connection string>").CreateCloudBlobClient(); });
```

[image]

Go to `Configure` method. Add a line code below :

```
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

[image]

3). Go to `Controller` folder , create a controller `BlobController.cs` with code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;

// For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace blobApitest
{

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
    public class BlobController : Controller
    {

        private CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient;


        public BlobController(CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient)
        {
            this.cloudBlobClient = cloudBlobClient;

        }

        [HttpPost()]
        public OkObjectResult upload([FromForm] IFormFile file)
        {

           string FileName = file.FileName;
           var container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("<your container name>");
           var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(FileName);

           blob.UploadFromStream(file.OpenReadStream());

           return Ok("uploaded");
        }

        [HttpGet()]

        public OkObjectResult GetAll() {

            var bloblist = new ArrayList();

            var container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("<your container name>");
            SharedAccessBlobPolicy ReadOnly = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
            {
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
            };

            var sas = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(ReadOnly);

            foreach (var blob in container.ListBlobs()) {
                bloblist.Add(blob.Uri+sas);
            }
            return Ok(bloblist);
        }

    }  
}
```

4) .Run this project.

Test result :

You will get an alert if you upload an imgae to storage successfully:
[image]

Lets check container,images has been uploaded successfully : 
[image]

Click show all images button , all images in your container will be displayed : 
[image]

Hope it helps .

Comment: In the blob controller there is an error in for each loop in ListBlobs(). It says CloudBlobContainer does not contain a definition for ListBlobs.When I change it to ListBlobsSegmentedAsync there is error as, for each statement cannot operate on variables of type Task<BlobResultSegment> because Task<BlobResultSegment> does not contain a public instance defenition for GetEnumerator. No overload method ListBlobsSegmentedAsync takes 0 arguments

Comment: Hi,@DuskHare maybe this error is due to involved some packages that useless. I have updated my code. ListBlobs() method belongs to class CloudBlobContainer of Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob . In my code its version is 11.1.1 the latest one , pls have a chcek in NuGet . If my answer is helpful , pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark it as an answer and I am glad to answer your further questions .

Comment: Hi @DuskHare , what's more , maybe this doc will be helpful for you to solve this issue : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list

Comment: Hi @StanleyGong , sorry for late reply. when i call the api I get following exception: "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient' while attempting to activate 'API.Controllers.BlobController'." I think you have to pass authorization header. What should I do.

Comment: also when i call the api from mvc i get 500 internal error as well as a cors not enabled error from my origin mvc

Comment: Hi @DuskHare, I am not sure why you will meet so many issues, it works perfectly. I have uploaded my demo project here , pls try it on your side: https://stanstroage.blob.core.windows.net/container2/blobApitest.zip